# How to change or add a value to an existing BlobPropertyBag

Tags: scala.js

Some JavaScript functions take an options parameter that can be created in Scala.js like this:

```
js.Dynamic
  .literal(
    "onload" -> onloadHandler _,
    "filename" -> s"myFileName.txt"
  )
  .asInstanceOf[BlobPropertyBag]
```

In one API, I can call a function to get some settings as a BlobPropertyBag (I assume), but need to change or merge in some values and use the settings again later.

Is there any way to work with these values? Convert them to String or JSON or something usable in Scala.js?

Should I be using a different type in the facade to read these values?

Comment: I haven't used `BlobPropertyBag` myself, but taking a quick glance at the documentation, I *suspect* you want to view it as a `js.Dictionary[Any]` for this purpose...

Answer (score 0):

If `BlobPropertyBag` were declared with `var` fields, you could simply assign its fields, obviously. However, as it is [declared with `def`s](https://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-dom/0.9.5/#org.scalajs.dom.raw.BlobPropertyBag), you'll have to cheat a little: cast it back to `js.Dynamic` to change one of its fields:

```scala
def foo(bag: BlobPropertyBag): Unit = {
  val mutableBag = bag.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic]
  mutableBag.type = "another type"
  // use `bag` afterwards
}
```